# Docker automatically removing the pulled images

Tags: docker, garbage-collection, docker-registry

I have the following docker version:

```
~> docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

The docker is automatically removing the unused images, this is leading to unnecessary image pull every time I am starting the docker image, is there any Docker settings that I can tweak? Why this is happening?

Comment: There's nothing automatic in docker that does this. You have a script or job running somewhere.

Comment: No, I don't see any process that will prune the images.